# Delete all duplicates except first one mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have a table with a column `serial_number` that is repeated a few times. How would I delete the entire row except the first duplicate?
By the following, I can select all the duplicates. But can't delete.

`SELECT serial_number, COUNT(*) FROM trademark_merge GROUP BY serial_number HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

[image: Result Image]

Comment: Incidentally, it's frequently quicker to create a new table, retaining only the rows you want to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the primary key of your table is `id`, you could phrase this as a delete/join query, like:

```
delete tm
from trademark_merge tm
inner join (
    select serial_number, min(id) id
    from trademark_merge 
    group by serial_number 
) tm1 on tm.serial_number = tm1.serial_number and tm.id > tm1.id
```